# Navigation controller toolbarItems array is nil?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In one app I work on, I have to put many (more than 5) toolbarItems on the toolbar of a UINavigationController, and need to replace one of the toolbar items when user taps it.

For making the code less clogging in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I set up navigation controller in storyboard (OK, maybe it's evil..) instead of programmatically. The toolbars displays all right. The only problem is I cannot grab toolbarItems in code:

`NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [[[self navigationController] toolbarItems] mutableCopy];`

`toolbarItems` is always nil. Thus I cannot get my hands on one of the toolbarItems and change it as I intend to.

Is it normal or I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I just fix it.. I should call `[self toolbarItems]` instead of `[[self navigationController] toolbarItems]`. Hope this post could help others.